# when use [person walk] in another class,throw "singnal SIGABRT",anyone can help me? i am just learnning xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

// -----------------------------------------------------------------

@interface Person : CCSprite
{
}
@property NSString * actions;

@property NSString* name;

@property NSString* status;

+ (instancetype)initWithPicture: (NSString *) pic;

-(void)walk;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

@end
```

above is @interface person.h

```
#import "Person.h"
@implementation Person
+ (id)initWithPicture: (NSString *) pic
{
    CCSpriteFrameCache* spriteFrameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
    CCSpriteFrame * bgSpriteFrame = [spriteFrameCache spriteFrameByName:pic];
    CCSprite * personSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:bgSpriteFrame];
    personSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
    return personSprite;
}

-(void)walk
{}@end
```

above is my person.m, however method named walk is empty

```
        #import "Person.h"
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        CCSpriteBatchNode* batchNode;
        Person * personA;

        @implementation _256Deathes
        {
        }
        - (instancetype)init
        {    
    if ((self = [super init]))
            {
              NSAssert(self, @"Whoops");

                CCSpriteFrameCache* spriteFrameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
                [spriteFrameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"256Deathes.plist"];
                batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"256Deathes.png"];
                batchNode.position = CGPointZero;
                [self addChild:batchNode];
                BackGround * bgSprite01 = [BackGround initWithPicture:@"earthA.png"];
                bgSprite01.position = ccp(0, 0);
                [batchNode addChild:bgSprite01 z:0 name:@"bgSpriteA"];
                BackGround * bgSprite02 = [BackGround initWithPicture:@"earthA.png"];
                [batchNode addChild:bgSprite02 z:0 name:@"bgSpriteB"];
                        }
        return self;
        }

        - (void)onEnter
        {
            [super onEnter];
            //updateSprite per 0.2s
            [self schedule:@selector(updateSprite) interval:0.02];
            //add person
            personA = [Person initWithPicture:@"personA/personAWalk0.png"];
            personA.position = ccp(100,100);
            [batchNode addChild:personA z:0 name:@"personA01"];
            //add person walk animate
            [personA walk];
        }
-(void) updateSprite
{
    [self updateBackGround01];
}

-(void) updateBackGround01
{
    BackGround *sprite;
    for(sprite in [batchNode children])
    {
            double nextX = sprite.contentSize.width-2;
            if(sprite.position.x <= (-nextX))
            {
                sprite.position = ccp(nextX, 0);
            }
    }

}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

@end
```

this is my another class, person is the subclass of CCSprite, 256Deathes is the subclass of CCSence
i am learnning cocos2s-iphone, these code throw a error "signal SIGABRT", and i don't know why, cann't find the reason
if delete the code "[personA walk]", it will be OK, so "[personA walk]" must be the reason, anyone can help me?thanks!
《---------------------------------------------------------------------------》
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLFox.png)

```
2016-12-25 22:02:40.786772 256deathes[6797:181749] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.787820 256deathes[6797:181749] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.800940 256deathes[6797:181734] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.816385 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
cocos2d: Cocos2D-Swift version 3.4.9-RC1
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 10.0 (0x0a000000)
cocos2d: 64 bit runtime
cocos2d: Multi-threaded rendering: 0
cocos2d: OpenGL Rendering enabled.cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:    Apple Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER:  Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:   OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-12.4.2
cocos2d: GLSL_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferClass: CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsClass: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsGL
cocos2d: CCRenderCommandDrawClass: CCRenderCommandDrawGL
2016-12-25 22:02:40.874 256deathes[6797:181672] cocos2d: viewDidLoad
cocos2d: Cocos2D-Swift version 3.4.9-RC1
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 10.0 (0x0a000000)
cocos2d: 64 bit runtime
cocos2d: Multi-threaded rendering: 0
cocos2d: OpenGL Rendering enabled.cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:    Apple Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER:  Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:   OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-12.4.2
cocos2d: GLSL_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferClass: CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsClass: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsGL
cocos2d: CCRenderCommandDrawClass: CCRenderCommandDrawGL
2016-12-25 22:02:40.880794 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: augraph, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.882862 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: audiocomp, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.904777 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: aurioc, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.906944 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: aurios, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.908871 256deathes[6797:181759] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: aqiotime, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.909252 256deathes[6797:181759] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: aqme, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.911241 256deathes[6797:181759] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: AudioHAL_Client, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:40.925862 256deathes[6797:181759] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: central, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:41.031 256deathes[6797:181672] Error: -[IOSVersion init]: Cannot parse iOS version string "10.0"
2016-12-25 22:02:41.037016 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, category: 3dml, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:41.069 256deathes[6797:181672] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00
2016-12-25 22:02:41.070 256deathes[6797:181672] cocos2d: surface size: 1136x640
2016-12-25 22:02:41.161 256deathes[6797:181672] cocos2d: surface size: 1136x640
2016-12-25 22:02:41.164447 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:41.166402 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:44.741523 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:44.742786 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:44.743157 256deathes[6797:181672] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-12-25 22:02:44.884 256deathes[6797:181672] -[CCSprite walk]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b2363b0a0
2016-12-25 22:02:44.902 256deathes[6797:181672] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite walk]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b2363b0a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010318c34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010237521e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001031fbf34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103111c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103111798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   256deathes                          0x0000000101b0ff11 -[_256Deathes onEnter] + 337
    6   256deathes                          0x0000000101a749f7 -[CCTransition startTransition:] + 135
    7   256deathes                          0x0000000101ad3ecc -[CCDirector replaceScene:withTransition:] + 108
    8   256deathes                          0x00000001019f8d75 -[IntroScene onSpinningClicked:] + 181
    9   256deathes                          0x0000000101a52ce7 __32-[CCControl setTarget:selector:]_block_invoke + 87
    10  256deathes                          0x0000000101a52dcd -[CCControl triggerAction] + 109
    11  256deathes                          0x0000000101a69cbc -[CCButton triggerAction] + 156
    12  256deathes                          0x0000000101a69b1c -[CCButton touchUpInside:withEvent:] + 172
    13  256deathes                          0x0000000101a53056 -[CCControl touchEnded:withEvent:] + 118
    14  256deathes                          0x0000000101af25ff -[CCResponderManager touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 623
    15  256deathes                          0x0000000101b1b9c8 -[CCGLView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 312
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001042450d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001042467c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001041f3a33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001049e5b6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001049de817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103131311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010311659c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103115a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103115494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108653a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001041d5f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  256deathes                          0x00000001019f8e31 main + 65
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105b7268d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

above is the error message, and walk method walk is in the person.h, any help, thanks

Comment: Please post the stack trace and full error message. You should know the exact line the problem occurs on as Xcode will show this; if it doesn't set an Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: The first things that come to mind are to change your `initWithPicture:` method to return `instancetype` instead of `id`. The second thing is to make sure you've put your `walk` method in the `@interface` of your `Person` class. Without more information, not sure what else it could be.

Comment: thanks for your suggests

Comment: but it does not work after a while i will update the question and add the infomation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `initWithPicture` method of `Person`.  It does not return a `Person` object but a `CCSprite` object.  Then, when you call `walk`, it tells you that a `CCSprite` doesn't know how to do that.

Create a real `Person` object as `self` and return that.

Comment: Oh thanks i think you are right, you remind me that i have saw that in the book. now i am outside tomorrow i will try, hope it works. Hahaha